# Reset Password in drupal 7

Tags: 7, users

I want following functionality when user click on forgot password.

I want user will get an email to rest his password. when he click the link, A new password wil generated and send into his email

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Drupal core provides the One time login link to reset the password. If you want to send a password then I think you need some custom code to do this.

Comment: @SumitMadan i dont want one time login.

Comment: Then the way to do it with custom module is that, you can alter the forgot password form and add your submit handler. Just set a random password of user and send it in mail.

Comment: I am wondering why you want the password sent by email? It sounds like a bad practise for obvious security reasons (password in the air, password available in mailbox..).

Answer (score 0):

By default Drupal has forget password functionality which will send the one time password link to the user. may be you can use this  https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_pass_reset module if it matches your requirement

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051390/change-admin-password-in-drupal-7